# Appium 1.6: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command during click and sendKey

Tags: java, appium

I have read several other similar topic questions but the question is not resolved. It just happens for a particular input field when testing my apps by:

```
Keyboard keyboard = driver.getKeyboard();

element.click();
keyboard.sendKeys("text");
```

Then I get the following log:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 56 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
>   System info: host: 'XXXXXXXX', ip: 'XXXXXXXXXXX', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
>   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver
>   Capabilities [{app=C:\XXXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXX.apk, appPackage=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXXXXX, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, appWaitPackage=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXX, appWaitActivity=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXX.MainActivity, app-package=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, app-activity=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=XXXXXXXXXX, version=5.1, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=XXXXXXXX, appActivity=com.ionicframework.welcome762668.MainActivity, desired={app=C:\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\XXXXXXXX.apk, browserName=, app-package=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXXXXX, app-activity=com.ionicframework.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.MainActivity, platformName=Android, deviceName=HUAWEI TIT-AL00, version=5.1}, platformVersion=5.1, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true, browserName=, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=Android}]
>   Session ID: 63186011-9ab0-443d-939e-7cc902ace5a4
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.PerformsTouchActions.performTouchAction(PerformsTouchActions.java:39)
>       at io.appium.java_client.TouchAction.perform(TouchAction.java:322)
>       at test.example.TestAppium.test(TestAppium.java:135)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: what are you trying to do ? 
There is no text to write with the send keys in your code !

Comment: Thank you, it should be text there, but I didn't check it, now that will be edited

Comment: please make it "text" not text without  " "